# 2008 Standard --> 2012 --> 2016 licence requirement

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2016

Hi I have a similar issue to [Upgrading Windows Server 2008 R2 to 2016 sequentially](https://serverfault.com/questions/936858/upgrading-windows-server-2008-r2-to-2016-sequentially)

but a) from 2008 Standard and b) I have only one server.

MSFT talks about going from 2008 -> 2012 -> 2016.  But I only of course want to pay for 2016.  Is this possible without doing a clean install?  As I only have one server I don't want to wipe what I have on it and have to reinstall and set it up again.

Comment: Buy a normal open license with SA; it allows you to up-and downgrade your installation as long as the SA is active.

Comment: bjoster you are correct.  My licence provider said 16 comes with downgrade rights to 12, they gave me two distinct keys and said as long as only one was active at any one time it was fine.  So I did: 2008 Standard ->  in place upgrade to 2012 -> activate 2012 and install updates -> in place upgrade to 2016 -> activate 2016

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft only sells licenses for the current version of products.  Microsoft also grants permission to use the previous version of their business products when you purchase a license. So there are no other licenses for you to purchase.

So yes, it is possible to perform an in place upgrade this way.